# Make Chathead bubble run forever in android

Tags: java, android, android-service

Hi I am trying to make a chathead bubble, like the one facebook has, for an app in android studio. I have been able to successfully display the bubble using Overlay and make it a service which continues to run even after the app is closed (not killed). However when I open another app or if I dont use my phone for more than 10 minutes, the chathead bubble disappears, unlike Facebook's bubble. How can I go about making the bubble display on the home screen and other apps for a longer period of time(potentially forever)?

For context, I used https://www.androhub.com/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-messenger-chat-head/ to make the bubble, using a `View` and a `Service`. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your app's service will get killed by the android system to save battery. There is no exact and easy way to do that. You have to implement multiple methods to do that.

1. Use Foreground Service(You may have already doing this but just in case if not.)
2. Ask for permission to restrict Battery Optimization.
3. In some devices like Xiaomi and Vivo, you need special permission to always run in the background ask for that.
4. Ask the user to lock the app in recent tab so it won't get killed by the system.

Comment: I tried using Foreground Service, but if I open another app, the service stops and I get an alert saying that my app has stopped working. Does android allow two foreground services to run at the same time?

Comment: Yes it does, check that if you have make it stop in your onPause method. If you did then remove that code.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are implementing the service, override onStartCommand() and return START_STICKY as the result. It will tell the system that even if it will want to kill your service due to low memory, it should re-create it as soon as memory will be back to normal.
2. If you are not sure 1st approach will work - you'll have to use AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html . That is a system service, which will execute actions when you'll tell, for example periodically. That will ensure that if your service will be terminated, or even the whole process will die(for example with force close) - it will be 100% restarted by AlarmManager.